# Why are not my balloons flying properly? Css animation translate

Tags: css, css-animations, translate3d

I am trying to do the following with CSS translate:

When a button is clicked, balloons appear and fly away. When they finished flying, they disappear and return to the starting position (so that when the next time a button is clicked the same behavior happens).

Up till now I got the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/w89bL/) (balloon is only flying up and does not appear / disappear).

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img class="object" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/balloon_PNG580.png" />
</div>
<br><br><button id="button">Fly!!!</button>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.object {
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.move-up{
    transform:         translate(0,-150px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-150px);
    -o-transform:      translate(0,-150px); 
    -moz-transform:    translate(0,-150px);
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.object').addClass('move-up');
});
```

The problem is that when I try it to appear with adding starting `display : none` to object and on click add `$('.object').show()` my animation does not start at all. How to may my balloon fly?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w89bL/1/)? Note that this sample uses animation.

Comment: @Harry yes, the only problem is that you can not click it next time.

Comment: That can be fixed by removing the `.move-up` on animation end like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w89bL/2/). If you are OK with this approach, I will add it as answer and explain more.

Comment: @Harry Thank you. Can you please post it as an answer, so that I can acknowledge you help? I also forgot to tell that in my starting question I stated that balloon should not be visible in the beginning and start to be visible only when click happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this effect using CSS3 animations. Please refer inline comments for more details on each item.

**CSS:**

```
.object {
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0; /* make the balloon invisible on load and once animation is complete */
}

.move-up{
    -webkit-animation: balloon 1s linear; /* the animation to move up */
    -moz-animation: balloon 1s linear;
    animation: balloon 1s linear;
}

@keyframes balloon { /* included only unprefixed version to keep answer short, demo has the prefixed versions also */
    5% {
        transform: translate(0, 0); /* keep at original position */
        opacity: 1; /* make opacity as 1 after a short time for balloon to appear */
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(0, -150px); /* move up */
        opacity: 1; /* retain the opacity */
    }
    55%, 100% {
        transform: translate(0, -150px); /* retain translated position till end */
        opacity: 0; /* hide the ballons and make it hidden for the rest of the duration */
    }
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.object').addClass('move-up'); // adding the move up animation class to make it move
    $('.object.move-up').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd',function(){
        $('.object').removeClass('move-up'); // removing the animation class on animation end to make it come back to original state
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w89bL/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a codepen using the translate property inside an animation. (My container has height 700px) .

```
@keyframes moveballoon { 
  0% {  transform: translate(0px, 700px);}
  100% { transform: translate(0px, -1200px);} 
}

.animationballoon { 
  animation: moveballoon 2s infinite linear forwards;
}
```

With Jquery you could have something like:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$('.object').addClass('animationballoon');
});
```

Hope it could help!

[DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/Pelucchi/pen/QjBKWQ)